# How to avoid Apple fee for a subscription based model that is only managed on the website

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I developed a chat app for people with depression or anxiety to have access to professional help immediately.

Basically, the client goes on a website, registers and enters his payment details to get an account. Then he can access to the website or app using his new account. So he can start chatting with a professional.

The app is created and now I received my first review from Apple.

There is no link to the website within the app and I don't want people to purchase services from the app. And I would like to avoid the 30% fee from Apple.

Do you have any advice on how to make it work?

Here is the first App Store Connect review:
[image]

Comment: Just answer the questions. Avoid using in app terms like trial, payment etc

Answer (score 1):

What you need to keep in mind: If you do not want to offer "Apple" in-app purchase, you cannot offer any other unlocking method in your app.

see 3.1.1 at https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments

But this is exactly what you wrote yourself. Just answer their questions accordingly.

Comment: This is their reply
Guideline 3.1.1


We noticed that your app or its metadata enables the purchase of content, services, or functionality in the app by means other than the in-app purchase API, which is not appropriate for the App Store.

Next Steps

While the payment system that you have included may conduct the transaction outside of the app, if the purchasable content, functionality, or services are intended to be used in the app, they must be purchased using in-app purchase, within the app - unless it is of the type referenced in guideline 3.1.3 of the App Store Review Guidelines.